# Transfrom line into two columns

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

Input:

```
IN22FDX_S1P_WWWWBBBBMMMCCCC_ffg_pre_0.59_0_.72_-40_nominal
```

Output:

```
IN22FDX_S1P_WWWWBBBBMMMCCCC ffg_pre_0.59_0_.72_-40_nominal
#                          ^
#                space instead of underscore
```

How to convert the above line to two columns (remove one underscore between them)? The first word is of fixed length `IN22FDX_S1P_WWWWBBBBMMMCCCC`.

Comment: is the number of `_`also fixed for first column string?

Comment: is your input a string or a file?

Comment: _ is just one. input is a line in a file

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the first column has a fixed size,

```
sed 's/./ /28'
```

replaces the 28th char with a space.

Assuming the data is stored in a file, you can edit it in place with sed.

```
sed -i.bak 's/./ /28' input_file
```

Note the `.bak` I added to the `-i` option; it instructs sed to make a backup file `input_file.bak` with the provided suffix. The suffix is optional.

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I was looking for. simple solution.

Answer (score 5):

**GNU `cut`** solution:

```
s="IN22FDX_S1P_WWWWBBBBMMMCCCC_ffg_pre_0.59_0_.72_-40_nominal"
cut -c 1-27,29- --output-delimiter=' ' <<<"$s"
```

- `-c` - to select characters

The output:

```
IN22FDX_S1P_WWWWBBBBMMMCCCC ffg_pre_0.59_0_.72_-40_nominal
```

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I was looking for but sed seems to bit more easy with syntax !